# How do I convert from 'Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, asp.net-core-3.1, proto

I want to map datetime  in **c#** datetime in **protobuf** .
Do you have any suggestion to do this?

Comment: Did you try to reach the documentation?

Comment: Yes but I didn't reach a conclusion, Do you any resources about it ?

Comment: Can you post the links to the documentation you have read and also add some code lines on the conversion, this way others can help you check for issues.

Answer (score 11):

If you mean the Google implementation: quite simply, [`FromDateTime` and `ToDateTime`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/timestamp#public-static-functions)

```
Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp protoTimestamp 
    = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

(I add that qualification because protobuf-net *also* defines similarly named types, which have implicit conversion operators to/from `DateTime`)

Comment: tnx for your help